# How to sort products according to category on the catalog page, and also show Category name?

Tags: magento2

So, I have 4 categories in magento store. Each category have two sub-categories, (Essential products, Additional products).

I want to sort products according to those sub-categories, "Essential Products" should come first. And I also Want to display the category name on top, so when the "Additional Products" start I want to show a heading saying "ADDITIONAL Products".

It is magento 2.4

I am kind of new to magento, so please elaborate your answer and include detailed resources if possible.

Answer (score 0):

To sort products according to sub-categories in Magento 2.4 and display category names as headings, you can follow these steps:

1. Go to Magento admin panel and navigate to Catalog > Categories.
2. Create your main categories and their sub-categories, such as "Category 1 > Essential Products" and "Category 1 > Additional Products".
3. Assign your products to the appropriate sub-categories.
4. Go to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Storefront and set the "Product Listing Sort by" option to "Position".
5. Go to Content > Blocks and create a new block for each category that you want to display on the front-end. For example, you could create a block with the identifier "category1_heading" and the following content:

> <h2>Category
> 1</h2>

- Go to Content > Widgets and create a new widget for each category that you want to display on the front-end. For example, you could create a widget with the following settings:
- Type: CMS Static Block
- Design Theme: Your current theme
- Widget Title: Category 1
- Assign to Store Views: All Store Views
- Layout Updates: Category View > Add Update
- Display on: All Pages
- Anchor: Yes
- Block Reference: Category Page Main Content Area
- Sort Order: 1
- Add Widget Options: Select "category1_heading" from the dropdown
  menu.
- Repeat steps 5 and 6 for each category that you want to display on the front-end.
- Create a new theme or modify your existing theme to customize the category page layout. To do this, you will need to create or modify the following files in your theme:
- app/design/frontend///Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
- app/design/frontend///Magento_Catalog/templates/category/products.phtml

9. In catalog_category_view.xml, add the following code to define a custom block for the "Essential Products" sub-category:

   ```
    <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
         <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="essential.products.heading" template="Magento_Catalog::category/essential_heading.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
   ```

This code adds a new block named "essential.products.heading" to the "category.products.list" block, which is responsible for displaying the list of products in the category. The block uses the "essential_heading.phtml" template, which you will create in the next step.

10. Create a new file named essential_heading.phtml in your theme's Magento_Catalog/templates/category directory, and add the following code:

    if($block->getCurrentCategory()->getName() == "Category 1"): ?>
    <h3>Essential Products</h3> endif;

This code checks if the current category is "Category 1" and displays the heading "Essential Products" if the condition is true.

11. In catalog_category_view.xml, add the following code to define a custom block for the "Additional Products" sub-category:

This code adds a new block named "additional.products.heading" to the "category.products.list" block. The block uses the "additional_heading.phtml" template, which you will create in the next step.

12. Create a new file named additional_heading.phtml in your theme's Magento_Catalog/templates/category directory